# How can I show a function is odd?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[-a,a]\to\mathbb R $ be a continuous function where $a>0$. If $f$ satisfies that $$\int_{-a}^a f(x)g(x)dx=0$$ for every integrable even function $g:[-a, a]\to\mathbb R$, show that $f$ is an odd function.

Would it be sufficient to just consider the case when $g(x)=1$?

Comment: It is definitely not enough to consider the case when $g(x) = 1$, as $a$ is fixed. For example, consider $f(x) = \cos x$ and $a = \pi$. Then $\int_{- \pi}^\pi \cos x \, dx = 0$, but $f$ is not odd.

Comment: use the integration by parts formula :)

Comment: @Sak There's no guarantee that anything here is differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Because $g$ is even,

$$\int_{-a}^a f(x)g(x)\,dx = \int_0^a [f(x)g(x) + f(-x)g(-x)]  \,dx = \int_0^a [f(x)+ f(-x)]g(x)\, dx.$$

Comment: From the line $\int_0^a [f(x)+ f(-x)]g(x)\, dx$ how to say that $f(x)=-f(-x)$ i.e f is an odd function?

Comment: @user1942348 Take $g(x) = f(x) + f(-x).$

Comment: If $g(x) = f(x) + f(-x)$, then $\int_0^a [f(x)+ f(-x)]g(x)\, dx=0 \implies \int_0^a g^2(x)\, dx=0$ I am unable to understand what you actually want to mean. Please help.

Comment: It seem to me that if $\int_a^b \phi(x) dx = 0$ then you are possibly want to say $\phi(x)=0, ~\forall x\in[a, b]$. If yes, why this conclusion is valid? If not, please help me to understand.

Answer (score 2):

No. If all you knew was that $\int_{-a}^a f(x) dx = 0$, you couldn't deduce that $f$ was odd.

If you let $g$ be a more interesting even function - for instance, the function that takes the value $1$ on $[-\alpha, -\beta] \cup [\beta, \alpha]$ and takes $0$ otherwise - you will get much more information. Make the interval $[\beta, \alpha]$ get smaller and smaller around any given point $x$. You will have to use continuity!